# spring data query select pageable entries within 30 days records

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data and am trying to write a query which returns all entries within 30 days. The following is my repository code

```
@Query(value = "SELECT rp FROM RequestPipeline rp JOIN FETCH rp.requestAudits where rp.createdAt >= :date", 
    countQuery="SELECT count(*) FROM RequestPipeline rp JOIN rp.requestAudits where rp.createdAt >= :date")
Page<RequestPipeline> findAllRequests(Pageable pageable, @Param("date") Timestamp date);
```

how to get within 30 days records? can any one help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`CURRENT_DATE` expression](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/date) and subtract 30 resulting in the following query:

```
SELECT rp FROM RequestPipeline rp JOIN FETCH rp.requestAudits where rp.createdAt >= CURRENT_DATE - 30
```

*Side note: in this case you shouldn't need the explicit count query. Spring Data should be able to derive it.*